# Call empty() on private attributes

Tags: php, oop

I'm using the `__get()` and `__set()` magic methods in order to intercept external calls to some private attributes without the need of writing a setter and a getter for each attribute. So far so good:

```
<?

class Foo{
    private $id;
    private $info = array();
    private $other;

    public function __set($name, $value){
        switch($name){
            case 'id':
            case 'info':
                return $this->$name = $value;
                break;
            default:
                throw new Exception('Attribute "' . $name . '" cannot be changed from outside the class');
        }
    }

    public function __get($name){
        switch($name){
            case 'id':
            case 'info':
                return $this->$name;
                break;
            default:
                throw new Exception('Attribute "' . $name . '" cannot be read from outside the class');
        }
    }
}

$MyFoo = new Foo;

$MyFoo->id = 33;
$MyFoo->info = array (
  'item_id' => '20',
  'issue' => '53',
);
try{
    $MyFoo->other = 44;
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo 'Exception raised as expected: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

Now I need to test whether certain attribute (an array) remains empty or not. I realized that `empty($MyFoo->info)` was always `false` so I looked up in the manual and I found `__isset()`:

> __isset() is triggered by calling isset()  or empty()  on inaccessible
>   properties.

However, it's not clear to me how I should implement `__isset()` in my code. I guess it's supposed to return true or false but... can I distinguish between being called via `empty()` or via `isset()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do it this way:

```
public function __isset($name) {
    return isset($this->$name);
}
```

In this case `isset($MyFoo->info)` and `empty($MyFoo->info)` will work as expected:

```
// isset($MyFoo->info) --> true
// empty($MyFoo->info) --> false
$MyFoo->info = array(1, 2, 3);

// isset($MyFoo->info) --> true
// empty($MyFoo->info) --> true
$MyFoo->info = array();

// isset($MyFoo->info) --> false
// empty($MyFoo->info) --> true
$MyFoo->info = null;
```

Comment: You are right. It seems that empty() triggers __isset() but it doesn't use its return value directly.

Comment: empty() first calls __isset(), then, if it returns true, __get() to check existing attribute's value for emptiness.